# QT - Why Affine Cipher Doesn't Decode?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption

Basically my problem is that I have a QT c++ program that encodes and decodes custom inputs based upon the Affine Cipher. The encoding function is working flawlessly based on the function that I found from Wikipedia, but the decode doesn't. When I run, it says that the modulo 26 cannot be applied to a double, and I understand that when I `pow(a, -1);` it returns a double, but I do not understand why it would do this in mine, but not on any other decoders. Here is the decode function, and my code:
[image]

Relevant code:

```
QString MainWindow::affineDecode(QString string)
{
    QString done = "";
    QString temp = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < string.length(); x++)
    {
        if (parseAlphaOnly(string.at(x)))
        {
            //Formula: a^-1(x-b)%26
            if (string.at(x).isLower())
            {
                //Broken code start:
                temp = alphabetLower.at((pow(ui->spinBox->value(), -1) * (getAlphaPos(string.at(x)) - ui->spinBox_2->value())));
            }
            else if (string.at(x).isUpper())
            {
                temp = alphabetUpper.at(pow(ui->spinBox->value(), -1) * (getAlphaPos(string.at(x)) - ui->spinBox_2->value())%26);
            }
            //Broken code end
        }
        else if (!parseAlphaOnly(string.at(x)))
        {
            temp = string.at(x);
        }


        done += temp;
    }
    return done;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean pow(ui->spinBox->value(), -1) is (a^-1) ? If yes, it's wrong you know

Comment: @AchmadJP What do you mean?

Comment: This is called inverse module in encryption algorithm. Exp : 3^(-1) mod 11  is 4. Not pow(3,-1) mod 11. Read it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: @AchmadJP So I would replace 'pow(ui->spinBox->value(), -1)' with 'ui->spinBox->value()^-1'?

Comment: @NicholasJohnson No, you replace it with the extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @AchmadJP How would I implement that into the code?

Comment: have you ever taken Cryptography class? if not, i suggest you to use encryption library, because it's complicated and 'most' people use library anyway for encryption process. But if you want to learn, then search for inverse module algorithm in google :)

Comment: @AchmadJP I that and I was reading and I couldn't find how to put it into code terms

Comment: @AchmadJP do either of you know how to actually implement it? Honestly, I just don't understand the wiki and don't want to use a library